# How to access xml nodes under a specific node using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
<testimonials>
<testimonial id="4c050652f0c3e">
    <nimi>John</nimi>
    <email>test@test.com</email>
    <text>Some text</text>
    <active>1</active>
    </testimonial>
<testimonial id="4c05085e1cd4f">
    <name>ats</name>
    <email>some@test.ee</email>
    <text>Great site!</text>
    <active>0</akctive>
</testimonial>   </testimonials>
```

Hi, I was trying to access xml nodes using Javascript. Can anyone explain me how to access all the nodes under the testimonial( with "id='4c050652f0c3e'").

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[attribute](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)** selector in jquery

```
$("[category=cooking]").children().each(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5kP7/3/)

Then you have to use direct id

```
 $("#4c050652f0c3e").children().each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works. can you explain me with Javascript.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3891074 JavaScript is little bit complicated compare with jquery ,jquery support all modern browser , and also i dont know fully in JavaScript,use jquery is best